# ¿Por qué se me niega el acceso remoto a mi servidor?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-server

Estoy manejando un servidor Ubuntu 20.04 desde mi consola en Windows. Estaba iniciando una aplicación web, pero para ello requería Nginx, lo instalé, luego al intentar conectarme nuevamente desde la consola, me doy con esta sorpresa:

```
C:\Users\MI_USUARIO>ssh -vvv USERNAME@HOST_SERVIDOR
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/MI_USUARIO/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname HOST_SERVIDOR is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to HOST_SERVIDOR [HOST_SERVIDOR] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10013, io:0000023164F63F40
debug1: connect to address HOST_SERVIDOR port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host HOST_SERVIDOR port 22: Permission denied
```

Así que abrí las direcciones indicadas en la tercera y cuarta línea y los archivos listados no están. Supuse que ese era el problema, pero no pasa de una suposición. Alguna ayuda por favor.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.